# CakePHP notices pre-fixed with 'Debug: '; go into debug.log

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I've just discovered that my application is logging Notices in debug.log instead of error.log. All notices seem to be prefixed with "Debug: ", e.g.:

> 2014-07-25 14:10:50 Debug: Notice (8):

Debug is set to 0 in core.php. I'm using a custom error handler, configured in core.php:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'MyErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
    'trace' => true,
    'api' => false
));
```

I have this in bootstrap.php:

```
App::uses('MyErrorHandler', 'Lib');

App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency', 'notice'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
```

If I move 'debug' from the debug config to the error config, debug messages go to error.log, but then so does the output from Debugger:log().

The issue seems to be that the notices are being prefixed with "Debug". Any ideas?

**Update**
See answer from @ndm
Here is the code I used in my custom mapErrorCode function to help resolve this:

```
case E_NOTICE:
case E_USER_NOTICE:
    $error = 'Notice';
    $levels = array_flip(CakeLog::levels());
    $log = ( isset($levels['notice']) ? $levels['notice'] : LOG_NOTICE );
```

Comment: This seems to make sense. A notice is a low level of error, so it should go into debug.log. So if you have Notices go to error.log, then all debug information will go there.

Comment: Not adding this as an answer as I'm not sure and I can't test it right now, but try dumping the `LOG_DEBUG` and `LOG_NOTICE` constants, what you are describing sounds as if it could happen in case they are holding the same value (which seems to be the case [**on windows systems**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.15/win32/syslog.h#L31-L33)), see **[`CakeLog::$_defaultLevels`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.0/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php#L90-L99)** and **[`CakeLog::defaultLevels()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.0/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php#L278)**.

Comment: Yes I'm running on Windows and both of those constants dump as '6'. CakeLog::$_defaultLevels is a protected array and CakeLog::defaultLevels() takes no arguments, so how do I change this? Do I need to make my own custom logger which inherits the default and overwrite in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

As mentioned in my comment, this behavior is caused by `LOG_DEBUG` and `LOG_NOTICE` holding the same value (`6`) on Windows systems, some people in the PHP team thought it might be funny to handle the OS differences (Windows doesn't have that many levels) exposed at user level, instead of translating the values internally.

**https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18090**

Internally `CakeLog` uses an [**error type (`string`) to error level (`int`) map**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.9/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php#L91-L100), which is being [**flipped**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.9/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php#L284) to create a map to retrieve the type by level, and so you'll end up with a map that looks like

```
array(
    (int) 1 => 'critical',
    (int) 4 => 'error',
    (int) 5 => 'warning',
    (int) 6 => 'debug'
)
```

which will cause `LOG_DEBUG`, `LOG_NOTICE` and `LOG_INFO` levels to be treated as `debug` types, as they are all holding the value `6`.

### A possible workaround

Working around this problem should be possible, but it might have some caveats. You could override the levels in `CakeLog` using `CakeLog::levels()` so that the types have individual levels:

```
CakeLog::levels(array(
    'emergency', 'alert', 'critical', 'error',
    'warning', 'notice', 'info', 'debug'
),
false);
```

would result in a map like

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'emergency',
    (int) 1 => 'alert',
    (int) 2 => 'critical',
    (int) 3 => 'error',
    (int) 4 => 'warning',
    (int) 5 => 'notice',
    (int) 6 => 'info',
    (int) 7 => 'debug'
)
```

Finally you'd need to use [**a custom error handler**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-your-own-error-handler) which maps the error codes to the proper levels, see `ErrorHandler::mapErrorCode()`, by default [**notices are mapped to `LOG_NOTICE`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.9/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php#L242-L245) (`6`), which you'd want to be `5` instead.

#### The problem with that might be

While this might work for PHP errors (like for example notices about undefined variables  and the like) that are flowing through the error handler, and custom calls to `CakeLog::write()` where you are explicitly passing the appropriate level, you may run into problems where the core or a plugin calls `CakeLog::write()` and passes hard-coded `LOG_*` constants, which would most likely cause the types to be written into the wrong log again.

However as far as I can tell the only place where such calls to `CakeLog::write()` appear in the core (yet), is in the error handler, so overriding this might do it for now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Before I try this out and accept the answer, can you clarify what you mean about internal errors vs. the core? Do you mean if an error occurs within one of the core CakePHP files rather than in something in my /app/ folder?

Comment: @gazareth By "internal" I ment native PHP errors like for example notices about undefined variables and the like, and regarding the core I was referring to possible explicit usage of `CakeLog::write()` (not necessarily in an error context) with hard-coded `LOG_*` constants, though it looks like that's not yet the case. I'll clarify that in my answer.

Comment: ok, so if I make reference to undefined variable called $variable in my app, it will still go to the debug.log? That is essentially the very use-case I would want to avoid. I have come across a few parts of the application where variables are not defined in certain scenarios and didn't realize until I checked my debug.log and it was full of these.

Comment: @gazareth No, it should go into your error log according to your log configuration (assuming my proposed workaround actually works ;)). I haven't had time yet to test it, but I'm going to right now.

Comment: @gazareth Just tested it and it works, notices are being prefixed with `Notice` and written to the error log, and when choosing the debugger to write to the logs instead of outputting JS it correctly writes into the debug log. However in order to be able to define where errors are being written to, you'll have to override pretty much the whole error handler as it's using `LOG_ERR` constants hard-coded (which I somehow overlooked).

Comment: OK I'll have a play later. I'm using my own error handler anyways o that shouldn't be too much of an issue...!

Comment: Have tested this myself now and it works perfectly for my purposes. For future reference, I copied ErrorHandler::mapErrorCode to my custom error handler and changed the notice section to the code I added at the bottom of my original question.